# Position absolute turned into position fixed on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

In the snippet below, you will see that I have two sections. One green and one blue. Then in the green section, there is a circle icon. Essentially what I am looking for is for the circle icon to be placed where it is currently on page load, but then as the user scrolls, for the icon to change to a fixed position until the blue section is at the top of the screen. Then when the user scrolls back up for the circle icon to do a reverse action and stay fixed until it gets back into its original position.

How can I do this?

```css
#slantWrap {
 height: 80vh;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
  background: green;
}
#redIcon {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 z-index: 2;
 margin: 0;
}
#redIcon img {
 height: 90px;
 width: auto;
}
#sec {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="slantWrap">
  <div id="redIcon">
    <img src="http://www.iconhot.com/icon/png/devine/256/circle.png" alt="icon">
  </div>
</div>
<section id="sec"></section>
```

Comment: position: sticky?

Comment: could you please include your js code where you have tried to achieve the effect so we can see the part where you are stuck. if you simply don't know where to start try [this](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) and [this](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
     if($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#sec').offset().top - 90){
      $('#redIcon').addClass('fixed');
     } else {
      $('#redIcon').removeClass('fixed');
  }
 });
```

So this function fires every time a user scrolls. What the if statement is looking for is, if the second `div` (Blue background) is 90px from the top of the window, (note that this `- 90` is the same height as the image) the add class of `fixed` if the the `#sec` div is NOT 90px from the top of the screen then remove the class of `fixed`. Lastly you will need to add this to your CSS to have a position fixed with the class is added.

```
#redIcon.fixed{
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
}
```

Working CodePen: https://codepen.io/ben456789/pen/OZPEpG

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. This is just about what I am wanting, but instead having the circle stay in place in the green section and then once the blue section hits the top for the icon to go away.

Comment: This is unclear, You want the circle to stay in the green section. Then when the blue section hits the top you want the icon to go away? if it stays in the green section it will go away because the blue section is now at the top of the screen.